# Amazon Quicksight adding new field to dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Hi I have been looking for some time to an answer to this but I really can not find one.

I have a dataset that is build from an S3 file.
this s3 file gets updated everynight and the dataset is refreshed soon after.

All the above works as you would expect. However if I want to add a field to the S3 file and see it in the dataset I can not seem to make this work.

I always get an error for every line of data that says `INCORRECT_FIELD_COUNT`
The documentation appears to suggest that adding a new field is fine so I assume there is something I need to do to make sure this works.

Any ideas?

I also posted here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=346538&tstart=0
but after posting about 5 questions and never getting an answer on there I thought I would try here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Edit your dataset
2. On the left you'll see a an "Excluded Fields" category (below the list of Fields). Expand it.
3. For each excluded field you'd like to include, click on the vertical dots and select "include field"
4. Save your dataset
5. Refresh your dataset to include the new fields